# Matlab and Java issue

Tags: java, matlab

I messed with the version of Java that I was using in Matlab and then I had some issues, so I tried to delete Matlab and all versions of Java from my machine then reinstall Matlab. According to,

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/130359-how-do-i-change-the-java-virtual-machine-jvm-that-matlab-is-using-on-windows

Matlab already has java in it, so I assumed that the fresh install of Matlab would fix the issue. But it did not and I ended up having to install Java and point to it as per the article above just to get Matlab working with Java again.

The issues are these:

1. When I start up Matlab, I get
   [image]
2. Sometimes it spools red errors and I have to shut Matlab off
3. I loose a lot of the interactive features, for instance; I cannot click on the folder ribbon to move through the folders as:
   [image]

3.b also, sometimes I cannot resize windows.

So, I lost some functionality. How can I run the version of Java that ships with the student version of Matlab?

Thanks!!

Comment: 1) Download the most recent JRE (1.8.*) and install it. 2) Setup your JAVA_HOME or JRE_HOME environment variables. 3) Logout, then log back in.

Answer (score 0):

I point the system MATLAB_JAVA variable to:

C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\sys\java\jre\win64\jre

Which is the original java version that MATLAB was shipped with. For some reason, the new java is buggy with the new matlab